# How to chain together two calls to dirname in qmake?

Tags: qt, qmake

Given the following in a qmake file:

```
SOME_PATH = "/path/to/folder/with/file.txt"
message("parent dir: $$dirname(SOME_PATH)")
message("grandparent dir: $$dirname($$dirname(SOME_PATH))")
```

It prints:

```
Project MESSAGE: parent dir: /path/to/folder/with
Project MESSAGE: grandparent dir:
```

How do I chain together two calls to `dirname` without needing to use an intermediate variable? Other replacement functions seem to work when chained, but this one does not.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be `dirname`? You could use `clean_path` to the same effect:

```
message($$clean_path("foo/bar/baz.txt/../../"))
```

prints:

```
Project MESSAGE: foo
```